# ¿Por qué declarar y usar dos size_t diferentes no falla?

Tags: c++, espacio-de-nombres

¿Este código no debería fallar?

```
#include <cstddef> // Contiene la definición de size_t

namespace mi_espacio_de_nombres
{
    using size_t = decltype(sizeof(nullptr));
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace mi_espacio_de_nombres;

    size_t s{};  // Esto no es ambiguo? std::size_t o mi_espacio_de_nombres::size_t?
    std::cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

En dos espacios de nombres diferentes tenemos la definición del símbolo `size_t`. En un contexto importamos ambos espacios de nombres y usamos dicho símbolo. ¿No debería quejarse de ambigüedad el compilador? Sin embargo el código [compila y se ejecuta](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4TIl6nPr79b1trZQ) sin problemas.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626881/can-defining-size-t-in-my-own-namespace-create-ambiguity-or-other-bugs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿No debería quejarse de ambigüedad el compilador?

No. Salvo que ambos símbolos fuesen diferentes.

---

En tu caso, tanto `std::size_t` como `mi_espacio_de_nombres::size_t` son el mismo tipo; la única diferencia entre ellos es el espacio de nombres al que pertenecen. [El estándar de C++](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/) nos indica que en este caso el compilador debe ignorar la posible ambigüedad o de manera más concreta sólo será un fallo [si ambos símbolos son diferntes pese a tener el mismo nombre](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#6) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 10.3.4 La cláusula `using`
>
> 6. Si la búsqueda de nombres encuentra **una declaración de un nombre en dos espacios de nombres diferentes**, y la declarción **no declara la misma entidad** y no declara funciones **el uso de dicho nombre es incorrecto**. [ *Nota*: en particular, el nombre de una variable, función o enumerado no oculta el nombre de una clase o enumerado declarado en otro espacio de nombres. Por ejemplo,
>
>    ```
>    namespace A {
>        class X { };
>        extern "C"   int g();
>        extern "C++" int h();
>    }
>    namespace B {
>        void X(int);
>        extern "C"   int g();
>        extern "C++" int h(int);
>    }
>    using namespace A;
>    using namespace B;
>
>    void f() {
>        X(1);    // error: X presente en dos espacios de nombres
>        g();     // CORRECTO: g se refiere a la misma entidad
>        h();     // CORRECTO: la sobrecarga se resuelve seleccionando A​::​h
>    }
>    ```
>
>    — fin de la nota ]

Sabemos que en tu caso `size_t` es la misma entidad porque precisamente, no ha fallado la compilación.